# IE 9 click fail in version of Expanding Thumbnail grid

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

The circles at the bottom of this site: http://benupham.com should open on click, but do not in IE 9 (and below, but concern is with IE 9). The JS is a modification of the example [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/). But I'm not even sure it's the js -- it could be the CSS. I'm viewing this bug through browserstack, which makes it very difficult for me to diagnose. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `transition` in the code, that specific event is not supported by IE 10, 9 or 8. To get a better idea of the browser support available for `transition` or any other CSS you could check it out here: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

If you're still having issues, I suggest showing some of your code and possible a gif of whats happening exactly.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that, but I have Modernizr checking in the Js, or rather the original developer did, and I have not made changes to that portion. Also, the transitions, which are added with jquery, are not being added in IE 9...I'm wondering if it could be the hover state on those circles, which are not in the demo code.